# n-th child selector

Tags: css

On [this page](http://www.festivals.ie/festival/show/1) I want to alternately rotate each artist photo to the left and to the right. The selectors I'm using to do this are

```
.artistsList img:nth-child(2n+1) {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
}

.artistsList img:nth-child(2n) {
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
}
```

But for some reason the 1st rule is being applied to all images, so they all get rotated to the left.

Comment: Can't you just use 'odd' and 'even' as the formulas? That's not your problem, just saying.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino actually I am using odd and even, but when you view the rules in firebug they appear as `2n+1` and `2n`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the HTML structure you've got. Every image is the first child of its parent. These selectors should work better for you:

```
.artistsList div.artistEntry:nth-child(odd) img { ... }
.artistsList div.artistEntry:nth-child(even) img { ... }
```